# Error al ejecutar comandos en angular/cli

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Actualicé mi proyecto angular 4 hacia la 5 y todo funciona bien. Pero cuando ejecuto el algún comando para generar clases, componentes, servicios, etc, me lanza un error, ejemplo:

```
ng generate class miClase 

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\AngularApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng generate class miClase 

Error: core_1.isObservable is not a function 
core_1.isObservable is not a function    
Done
```

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Prueba con lo siguiente: `npm remove -g @angular/cli` luego
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`, te actualizara el _CLI_ y suele reparar estos errores ya que son del _CLI_

Comment: actualicé la versión del angular/cli y nada